# How to fix HttpErrorResponse 404 Not found

Tags: c#, angular

I am getting error message on web console, it says "Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/api/authregister: 404 Not Found". I tried looking for solutions online, but it did not help. How do I fix this issue?

[image: pic1]

I tried to see if Postman worked with "GET" and it did work, however on "POST" it will not update database and get no response.

[image: pic2]

I checked database for update result and nothing has changed, I only have 2 username and passwords there:

[image: pic3]

**UPDATE:** I found the reason why I was getting the this ip address:

> http://localhost:5000/api/authregister

On baseUrl, I was missing a '/' on **auth.service.ts**, however I am now getting "Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register: 400 Bad Request". Here is **auth.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {map} from'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ //inject to service
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/'; //I added a '/' to the end

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

login(model: any) {
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model)
  .pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      const user = response;
      if (user) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
      }
    })
  )
}

register(model: any) { //need authservice in register component constructor
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'register', model);
  //return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'auth/register', model);
}


}
```

Here is AuthController.cs

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DatingApp.API.Data;
using DatingApp.API.Dtos;
using DatingApp.API.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens; //Symmetric Security Keys

namespace DatingApp.API.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAuthRepository _repo;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public AuthController(IAuthRepository repo, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
        _repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto) //get username and password, [FromBody] gives hint where info is
    {
        userForRegisterDto.Username = userForRegisterDto.Username.ToLower(); //make username lowercase

        if (await _repo.UserExists(userForRegisterDto.Username)) //check if User exist
            return BadRequest("Username already exist"); //BadRequist requires ControllerBase

        var userToCreate = new User
        {
            Username = userForRegisterDto.Username //APIModels
        };

        var createdUser = await _repo.Register(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);

        return StatusCode(201);
    }

    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto)
    {
        //throw new Exception("Computer says no!");

        var userFromRepo = await _repo.Login(userForLoginDto.Username.ToLower(), userForLoginDto.Password);

        if (userFromRepo == null)
            return Unauthorized();

        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userFromRepo.Id.ToString()), //token claims Id
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userFromRepo.Username) //token claims username
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
        .GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)); //MUST set TOKEN in appsettings.json

        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = creds
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler(); //to make token

        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        return Ok(new {
            token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token)
        });
    }


}
}
```

Comment: The obvious answer is that the server doesn't have a route that matches `api/authregister`
What do you have configured in your route/controller for your endpoints?

Comment: I added AuthController.cs to the description, you can check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your Controller code, your api route is `api/auth/register`, so you're just missing a `/`. Change it to call `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register` and you should have more luck.

To clarify, when you have this in your controller: `[Route("api/[controller]")]` It tells the routing that every end point in that controller will begin with a route of `api/auth` (in other words `[controller]` signifies the portion of the controller name prior to the `Controller` word.

When you then tag the end point method with `[HttpPost("register")]` it tells the routing engine that you expect to receive `POST` requests on an end point that appends `/register` to the end of the route for that controller.

So in other words `api/auth/register` will execute the `public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)` method.

If you check your `ValuesController` you'll probably see the same attribute tag at the top of the controller telling it to use the route `api/values`, however when you get to the get method it probably has an attribute of `[HttpGet]` which tells it that any `GET` request to `api/values` should just execute that method. There's no need for any addition to the path.

Make sense?

Comment: Do you mean to change it to this: [Route("api/[controller]/")] ?

Comment: @AlexH I updated the answer to give some further detail on how route attribute tags work.

Comment: I added / on how I said above, but apparently I still have the same issue.

Comment: ok I see the problem now, the expected url is http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register. But it is not showing /. So why didn't adding a / worked here?

Comment: I found out why I was getting incorrect URL, on description I added the reason why I was getting it, however now I have a 400 Error Bad Request. Should I make a new question instead?

Comment: Yes, ask a new question, but spend a bit of time trying to debug first.

Comment: Actually, I figured out why it was getting error 400, it was missing some parentheses in an html file.